# Are $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ the only canonically totally-ordered rings?

Tags: ring-theory, integers

**Definition 0.** Given a ring $R$, write $\mathbb{N}_R$ for the set $\{n \cdot 1_R : n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$ So:

$$\mathbb{N}_R = \{0_R,1_R,1_R+1_R,\ldots\}$$

**Definition 1.**  Write $\lesssim_R^\mathbb{N}$ for the preorder on $R$ defined as follows:

$$a \lesssim_R b \iff \mathop{\exists}_{n \in \mathbb{N}_R} a+n=b$$

**Definition 2.** Call a ring $R$ *canonically totally-ordere*d iff $\lesssim_R$ is both antisymmetric and total.

**Question.** Are $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ the only canonically totally-ordered rings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch: Suppose $R$ is canonically totally ordered. Since the order is total, $R=\left\{\pm n\cdot 1_R:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ (just compare terms with $0$). In particular $R$ is cyclic, as an additive group, so it is either $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n$. In the latter case, every element is $\geq 0$ and $\leq 0$ (by definition of the order), so antisymmetry implies every element is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You could loosen your definition to say rings need not have an identity, in which case any such ring satisfies the relation.

Comment: How do you propose to define $\mathbb{N}_R$ without an identity?